# Eclipse export mingw c++ linker Libraries Settings

Tags: eclipse, linker, export, settings, ld

Would want to know if there is a way to export Library Linkages from an eclipse project to another project.

I know I can export project settings which will include the Include Paths and Symbols, It shall export an xml file that contains the included path of the project. However I tried exporting from one project setting and imported to another project, it does not contain the Library search path and Libraries.

I see that in the Project properties ==> C++ General ==> Path and Symbols ==> Library paths, there existed a button of export and unexport, which in the help it states "Toggle selected library path exported or not". I honestly have no idea what it meant, and have tried Exporting settings toggling and untoggling Library Paths, but never did the exported setting contained the Library Paths and Libraries.

I then checked under the .cproject xml file and found that the Library Paths of the project are stored under

```xml
<storageModule moduleId="org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings">
<cconfiguration id="cdt.managedbuild.config.gnu.mingw.exe.release.1199744453">
<storageModule buildSystemId="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.configurationDataProvider" id="cdt.managedbuild.config.gnu.mingw.exe.release.1199744453" moduleId="org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings" name="Release">
<externalSettings>
<externalSetting>
<entry flags="RESOLVED" kind="libraryPath" name="D:\lib"/>
```

And Libraries are under

```xml
<storageModule moduleId="org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings">
     <cconfiguration id="cdt.managedbuild.config.gnu.mingw.exe.release.1199744453"><storageModule moduleId="cdtBuildSystem" version="4.0.0">
          <configuration artifactName="${ProjName}" buildArtefactType="org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.buildArtefactType.exe" buildProperties="org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.buildArtefactType=org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.buildArtefactType.exe,org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.buildType=org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.buildType.release" cleanCommand="rm -rf" description="" id="cdt.managedbuild.config.gnu.mingw.exe.release.1199744453" name="Release" parent="cdt.managedbuild.config.gnu.mingw.exe.release">
              <folderInfo id="cdt.managedbuild.config.gnu.mingw.exe.release.1199744453." name="/" resourcePath=""><toolChain id="cdt.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.mingw.exe.release.40688961" name="MinGW GCC" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.mingw.exe.release">
                    <targetPlatform id="cdt.managedbuild.target.gnu.platform.mingw.exe.release.432169143" name="Debug Platform" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.target.gnu.platform.mingw.exe.release"/><tool id="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cpp.linker.mingw.exe.release.519530359" name="MinGW C++ Linker" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cpp.linker.mingw.exe.release"><option id="gnu.cpp.link.option.libs.2025065282" name="Libraries (-l)" superClass="gnu.cpp.link.option.libs" valueType="libs">
                        <listOptionValue />
```

So I think there should be a way to export it.

I am just trying to avoid having to manually redo all the library linkages in each project, or perhaps I got some wrong idea about how library linkages work, any enlightenment is welcomed.